# The, um, Seder of the Seder

Tags: minhag, passover, passover-seder-hagada

Since I have only experienced a handful of families' traditions of how they conduct their Sedarim, I thought I'd ask what others do.

What are some of the widely practiced customs for how to actually conduct the Seder? By conduct, I mean who reads when (eg., does the "leader" read everything, or do you go around the table, or do you call for volunteers?), who is responsible for various parts (eg., opening the door for Eliyahu), what is acceptable to skip (eg., songs if it is getting late?), etc.

Please cite sources if possible, whether they be ancient or contemporary (even a blog). I'm not so much curious about what the RaMBa"M (eg.) [says we *should* do](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/3510.htm), as I am about what people are actually doing.

Comment: This is a very, very broad question. Perhaps split it into several? E.g., "what parts do y'all skip if it's late", "who reads when", "who opens the door", "when do you pour _Eliyahu_'s cup and who does it", etc.

Comment: @msh210, Alright, bear with me as I cut and paste. Are you sure it won't get burdensome to people answering?

Comment: I cannot be sure of anything. If anything, I'm more sure that there will be at least *one* person who finds it more burdensome. Nonetheless, I think that leaving this question as it is will invite all sorts of answers that have nothing to do with one another (one about this aspect of the question and another about that) and make this page hard to read. Consider also "If you can imagine an *entire book* that answers your question, you’re asking too much." (from [the FAQ list](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)).

Comment: I'm closing this as a temporary measure to bar answers until it's been edited. Ping me with `@msh210` to reopen it please.

Comment: For the record, I would have enjoyed seeing various answers along the lines of "My father makes Kiddush and recites all the blessings and leads all the rituals, and we take turns reading. We all pour wine for each other, and my my mother brings my father a cup of water and a bowl to wash his hands before Karpas (everyone else remains seated without washing, except for one cousin who washes in the kitchen because he insists on washing without a Berachah). We generally sing the songs responsively except for Echad Mi Yodeya, which we read as fast as we can to try to get each verse in one breath."